# A problem hearing audio

Tags: discussion

I have a audio from an Australian TV show. I am unable to understand a line in it. Is there any forum where I can upload the audio and someone can listen to it and answer that.

The guy was dreaming something and his father come and starts to yell at him

I want to know what he says after cut that off...
The link is here

Listen to Neighbours - 001 - Cut by Sukhjinder Singh #np on #SoundCloud
https://soundcloud.com/sukhjinder-singh-626913618/neighbours-001-cut

Comment: You can include the link to the video here and mark the problematic time.

Comment: Also, if the video is on YouTube, make sure you check to see if captioning is available first. We recently had a “What does this person say in the video?” question, and all the asker needed to do was hit the `CC` button and the answer was right there.

Comment: I uploaded a link please listen to it and answere

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for transcription of an audio file, not a question about learning English.

Comment: Why closing..? This is the way of learning english as well

Comment: Yes, but "what does this particular file say?" is not a topic of general interest that is likely to help other learners.

Comment: Yes off course it will. I bet even you will find it difficult to understand

Comment: Asking for a written translation of an audio file that's difficult to understand due to problems in audio quality or a speaker's accent is not directly related to understanding the English language.

Comment: If its not related to understanding english what is this then

Comment: It's related to understanding English but IMHO this question is "too local" and will not help very many people.  The chat may be a bit better for this type of thing, or search for English learning forums on Reddit.

Comment: Do not repost questions that have been closed. The correct way to handle it is to edit the original question to bring it on-topic.

Comment: @ColleenV he posted the same question on EL&U meta https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11669/listen-and-answer So this is one very stubborn individual.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think that it was confusing and that no harm was meant or done except for a little moderation book keeping stuff.

Answer (score 2):

There are two voices. The first is a young man who is having a nightmare. The second is an older male who wakes him up.

Voice 1: (Making sounds, but no articulate words)

Voice 2: Hang on. Cut that out, cut that out, come on.

Voice 1: What's wrong.

Voice 2: You've been screaming the fl..place down again, that's what.
(NOTE: The 'fl' is a cut off word. The speaker was probably going to say 'flaming' but realised that the script actually required him to say that a few seconds later, so he stopped and went on with the rest of the script.)
('Flaming' in the sense it was going to be used is a common British (and Australian) word that is used to express annoyance about something, and is usually used as a more acceptable variant of a very common swear word "F---ing".)

Voice 1: What do you mean screaming.

Voice 2: Oh, get back to sleep will ya, and shut up for Pete's sake it's two o'clock in the flaming morning.